# Continuous functions whose Riemann sums are zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

here is my question : Let's denote $F$ the following set 
$$
F=\left\{ f \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{C}) / \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f \left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) =0 \right\}.
$$
$F$ contains the line spanned by $f_0 : x \in [0,1] \mapsto \sin (2 \pi x)$ (but not $\cos$ because of $n=1$), but is it bigger ?
I hope not, but I may be wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You meant $\sin(2\pi t)$?

Comment: What do you mean by the line spanned by $\sin$? All the $\alpha \sin x$ maps?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will correct it.

Comment: F is a subspace of the vector space of functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$. So by the line spanned by $f_0 : x \in [0,1] \mapsto \sin (2 \pi x)$, I mean the set of functions $f$ for which there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f = \alpha . f_0$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb N^*$ mean $\{1,2,\dots\}$ here?

Answer (score 3):

In fact one can prove that
$$S^\prime=\left\{ f \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{C}) \mid \forall x \in [0,1/2), f(1/2+x) = -f(1/2-x)  \text{ and } f(0)=0 \right\}$$

is included in $F$.

The proof is a consequence of the fact that for $f \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ satisfying for all $x \in [0,1/2)$, $f(1/2+x) = -f(1/2-x)$, you have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f \left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) =f(0).$$

In particular the function
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
x & 0 \le x < 1/4 \\
-x + 1/2 & 1/4 \le x < 3/4 \\
x-1 & 3/4 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$
belongs to $S^\prime$. Therefore $S^\prime$ is much bigger than $\operatorname{span}\{\sin(2 \pi t)\}$.

And one can prove that it exists non trivial even (at $1/2$) continuous functions belonging to $F$. See the answer to [Are those two subsets of $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614948/are-those-two-subsets-of-mathcalc00-1-mathbbr-equal)

Comment: For skim readers/lazy people: this completely answers the question. (The bolded sentence about $F\subset S'$ is just an interesting follow-on question, asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614948/are-those-two-subsets-of-mathcalc00-1-mathbbr-equal.)